# Forbidden, you don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: apache, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to create a site called sitb in ubuntu using apach2. I create a html file and saved it in a created siteb folder in var/www but when I load the site it just says Forbidden, you don't have permission to access this resource. I am not sure why I am getting this because I set the permissions to 755 for siteb

Here is my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/default>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/siteb>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your not looking in the right place, although the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file you pasted is giving you some big clues.

You also didn't give any information on what the host name is, or where you put the "html file".

Ubuntu uses the debian way of configuring apache2, so the config files for your "virtual-hosts" will be in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Take a look inside that directory and you should se a file called something like 000-default.conf. Take a look at it.

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
ls -la
cat 000-default.conf
```

You can either edit that default file or create a new one for your domain. Assuming you want to create a new virtual host configuration for the domain **example.com**, you would need to do the following steps. swap out example.com for the name of you domain.

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo cp 000-default.conf example.com.conf
sudo mkdir /var/www/example.com
sudo mkdir /var/www/example.com/public_html
sudo echo '<h1>This is the index file of example.com' > /var/www/example.com/public_html/index.html
sudo chown -R 775 /var/www/example.com/
```

Now you have a config file called /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf, a web root at /var/www/example.com/public_html and an index.html file in the web root.

Next you need to modify the config file for your domain name (remember swap example.com for your domain name:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

The file should end up looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you have made the changes to the config file, you need to enable the virtual host. This involves creating a symlink to your config file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/. Apache2 has a helper to do this:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
```

You can also disable the 000-default config if you want:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Now the preparation is finished, you need to restart apache for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

There area tons of documentation on the web on configuring apache on ubuntu, ask google.
Or maybe take a look at this document which is quite an easy read:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: This didnt solve my problem but I found it very educational. Thanks.

Comment: apache2.conf file specify directory where it can read. ie: "It does not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www". If we want to put our sources somewhere else, we have to add <directory> tag with the path to the sources either in our sites-available conf file or directly in apache2.conf.
Example:
<Directory /opt/dev/mywordpress_sites/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 5):

apache2.conf file specify directory where it can read, ie: "It does not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www".

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If we want to put our sources somewhere else, we have to add a `<directory />` tag with the path to the sources either in our /etc/apache2/sites-available/xyz.conf file or directly in apache2.conf.
Example:

```
<Directory /opt/dev/mywordpress_sites/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And on localhost, as long as we don't have domain name server resolution and that we are 'listening' on port 80, it is important to disable the 000-default.conf file and enable the one we want to work on.

In addition, on linux we have to add the name of our server 'xyz' in the /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.1.1       xyz
```